# How to select this div element from js.erb view

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm maing an ajax request to get all ratings when the page is loaded. This rendering is done in a js.erb view in rails. I want to edit the data-rate-value of the div but I cannot select it with the class and id at the same time. How do I select this div and change this attribute from a rails js.erb view?

```
       <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
           <div class="thumbnail">
               <div class="rating" id="<%= movie.id %>" data-rate-value=0></div>
               <%= link_to (image_tag movie.image.url(:medium), class: 'image'), user_movie_path(movie.user, movie) %>
               <% if movie.user == current_user %>
                   <br>
                   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_movie_path(movie.user, movie), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                   <%= link_to "Remove", user_movie_path(movie.user, movie), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You Sure?" }, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
               <% end %>
           </div>
        </div>
   <% end %>

This is my faulty solution

@ratings.each do |rating| %>
   $(".rating#<%= rating.movie.id %>").attr("data-rate-value", "<%= rating.score %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: `I cannot select it with the class and id at the same time` what do you mean by that? do you see any error? have you tried the selector manually on the browser console? using just a number as an element's ID doesn't sound good, it's easy to have multiple elements with the same ID by error. Use something like `movie_#{movie.id}` as the id of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be define your div id like this:

```
<div class="rating" id="rating_movie_<%= movie.id %>" data-rate-value=0></div>
```

and call in selector

```
$("#rating_movie_#<%= rating.movie.id %>").attr("data-rate-value", "<%= rating.score %>");
```